# Having trouble punching a hole in firewall

Tags: networking, router, firewall

I am having trouble punching a hole in my Uverse router. It is a model 5268AC. I use Settings, Firewall, Applications, Pinholes and DMZ. Then select my computer by using the IP address (in my case it is 192.168.1.71). I leave Maximum protection with a check mark. I leave the program blank because I just want any TCP port to go to my computer. I then click Save and Commit. I get my external IP address from the router using Settings, Broadband, Status and look at IP Address. Finally I use Telnet to send some TCP data and look for it at my computer. Since I’m having trouble I use Wire Shark to see what is going on. 
This has always worked with all of my previous AT&T routers.
Here is the telnet session:

```
telnet 99.181.11.158 3260
Connecting To 99.181.11.158...Could not open connection to the host, on port 3260: Connect failed
```

Here is a clip from WireShark:

```
192.168.1.71  -> 192.168.239.1 SYN
99.181.11.158 -> 192.168.1.71  RST
```

Eddy

Comment: Try from a computer on a different network - many SOHO routers don't work properly when accessing LAN computers via public IP.

Comment: This will only work if your router supports [NAT Reflection/NAT Loopback/NAT Hairpinning](http://www.nycnetworkers.com/real-world/nat-reflectionnat-loopbacknat-hairpinning/). Most consumer grade routers don't. You need to try access from an external network.

Comment: I'v tried it from another network. Same problem. This has worked with other routers for about 10 years. But long ago I did run into a case where a tech at AT&T told me that they block incoming ports. I wonder if that is the problem. Does anyone know about that?

Comment: Now I'm thinking that the UVERSE router port forwarding doesn't work. I have read online that I can use a separate router connected in parallel and I'll try that.